# Not able to access stackoverflow account with deactivated Yahoo account?

Tags: support, login

My wife was accessing her Stack Overflow account with Yahoo credentials till a month back. But some how her Yahoo account has been deactivated, because she did not login in Yahoo mail since a long time.

She was just using Yahoo credentials to login to Stack Overflow. But the issue is that a deactivated Yahoo account can not be activated again as per
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071215213117AArpE3j.

She wants to continue with her old Stack Overflow account as she owns a good amount of questions/answers under that profile.

How can we proceed under this scenario?

**UPDATE:-** Can stackoverflow core team hel me here or is there any other stackoverflow platform where they can provide quick help?

Comment: Why don't you create a new account and request to merge your old account with new one. If there is not much reputation loss just proceed with new account

Comment: satpal for merging the old account with new account, i need to login to my old yahoo account(which is not possible for deactivated account) as per http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts.

Comment: Also as per link http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts "If you can't remember how to log into one of your accounts, go here and enter the email address you used to create it.", it send the password at my deactivated yahoo account. So no help

Comment: If you want faster help, try http://stackoverflow.com/contact